# sample xsd files from geographic sources

Tags: gml, tiger, inspire

Where can I download sample xsd files for different features like road,rail,river,land etc.I need them urgently for checking the working of my project which works on the schema of geographic data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in INSPIRE data (as per your tag) then you should look at the INSPIRE site, for example [INSPIRE xml schemas](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm/pageid/2/list/xml-schemas) would seem a good place to look.  These though aren't samples, they are actual schemas that data providers need to follow.

If you're interested in Geology then you should look no further than [GeoSciML](http://schemas.geosciml.org).

If you're after Geography Markup Language then try http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/